# Automatically enabling wifi on system startup

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, toshiba-laptop

I am using a laptop (Toshiba Satellite L755) with an inbuilt wifi chip (Atheros ar9002wb-1ng) with Win7.

For some reasons wifi is not automatically enabled on startup, i.e. the wifi adapter doesn't see any networks, although the icon says it's active. I always have to manually switch it off and on again using hardware buttons. Once I have done that, windows lists me available wifi networks and I can connect.

I updated windows and installed the latest wifi driver from the Toshiba web page, but the problem remains..

What do I have to configure to be automatically connected on system startup?

Comment: Does Atheros or Toshiba provide software to manage your wireless connections?

Comment: I do believe @Ramhound may have given you a good direction... Toshiba laptops do usually have a separate application for managing wireless - completely pointless because Windows does a perfectly good job of it itself...

Comment: It's a long shot (as I had the same issue, but on my Dell XPS with Windows 10) but try launching the device manager, right-clicking the WiFi device under `Network adapters` and deselecting the option `Allow the computer to turn off the device to save power` (in the `Power Management` tab). If there is a `Transmit power` option (in the `Advanced` tab) then you may also want to try setting this to maximum.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a good solution but you can **create a batch script** that **turns off the WiFi interface and turn it back on** and **schedule it** to run every time you turn on your machine.

Since restarting seems to solve the problem, and having updated all your drivers does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious troubleshooting will be to ensure you have the most current driver for your Atheros WiFi chipset. You should go to the Toshiba site and look for what they offer for your particular model machine.

You should also check to ensure the WLAN AutoConfig Service is set to Automatic and started when this issue occurs.

Comment: As I wrote above: I updated windows and installed the latest wifi driver from the Toshiba web page, but the problem remains..

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

What worked for me was to remove the laptop battery and unplug the power adapter. Then I held the power button down on the laptop for over thirty seconds. Reconnect everything again and wifi should now work automatically after sleep hibernate and restart. Good luck!

Comment: What could holding the power button down when there is no battery or power going into the laptop possibly achieve?